# Single Gallery from multiple sharepoint list (all same fields)

Tags: sharepoint, logic, sharepoint-online, powerapps, powerapps-formula

Currently my powerapp is having a Gallery which is based on a single sharepoint list but **i would like to implement a gallery on my app which should show items from 3 different sharepoint lists (all have same columns/fields)** and i am using a filter on the galley so that user can type on the box and get filtered response only instead of showing all data

Please Help

I am already having this formula in gallery1.items :

Search('PO list', TextSearchBox.Text,"Branch_x0020_Code")
 For example,consider i have 2 list : list 1 & list 2 ,now when an user searches in the searchbox (i.e. TextSearchbox) i want the gallery to filter the data wherein "Branch_x0020_Code" equals search data from both the List

EDIT 1 : This is the formula i am trying to implement : 
Formula  : *ClearCollect(Aitems,'PO list',PO 2)*

and error is shown as in the following image:

[image: error]

My *"PO List"* was having a column called status and its type was Single line of text whereas in *"PO 2"* the type of status column was Choices .since i cannot change the datatype i have changed one of the list column name to *"Status 0"* .
Now the only difference i have between these two lists are one list has some extra columns while other don,t have.
But still when i am trying ti implement i am getting this *"Incompatible type"* error.

Answer (score 2):

Galleries can't directly show results from multiple data sources at one time. However one way to achieve this is to first collect data from the various lists into a single [collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/create-update-collection), then bind the gallery to that collection.

For example you could do this in the [OnStart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/controls/control-screen) property of the app, or the OnSelect property of an "update" button:

```
ClearCollect( CombinedListsCollection,
 List1, List2, List3 )
```

Then bind the gallery.items to the collection instead:

```
Search( CombinedListsCollection, TextInput.Text, [columns])
```

Another way to get at this is to collect dynamically a filtered set of records as your users search. For example, on your Text Input control for the search box, set the "OnChange" property to:

```
ClearCollect(CombinedFilteredLists,
Filter(List1, StartsWith(Title, TextInput1.Text)),
Filter(List2, StartsWith(Title, TextInput1.Text)))
```

Then set the gallery items to CombinedFilteredLists.

Use [StartsWith()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-startswith) wrapped in Filter() to delegate over large SharePoint lists as in the example above.

Here's a gif of that in action:
[Combining two SharePoint lists into one Gallery in PowerApps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkMnT.gif)

Comment: i tried both the solution given by you ,but i am getting error when i am adding second list in the formula"ClearCollect( CombinedListsCollection,List1, List2, List3 )",the error says Clearcollect has some incorrect arguments but the same works fine with only one list and the same applies to the second formula also wherein it works fine when i use like "ClearCollect(vvv,Filter('PO list', StartsWith(Branch_x0020_Code, TextSearchBox.Text)))" and gives same error when i add second filter statement with the second list

Comment: I am getting **Incompatible type error** in clear collect formula in both cases @Ryan Cunningham

Comment: @Vishnu, can you post the exact expression that you have with the two filter statements?

Comment: ClearCollect(CombinedFilteredLists,
Filter(List1, StartsWith(brcode, TextInput1.Text)),
Filter(List2, StartsWith(brcode, TextInput1.Text)))

Comment: @carlosfigueira

Comment: @Vishnu, do you have lists called `List11` and `List2`, and the types of their columns are exactly the same? For example, if I have a list (or a local collection) called `List1` with columns `brcode` (of type text) and `Value` (of type **number**), I'll see a similar error if my `List2` has a column `brcode` (of type text) and `Value` (of type **text**). Can you update your question (which has more space than the comments) with the description of your lists that you're trying to combine?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the exact same columns/fields for the two lists, then Ryan's solution would work. However, if some of the fields are different (either their name or type), then you can use [one of the many functions that can help you change the "table shapes"](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-table-shaping) in PowerApps.

In your specific case, if you have the following two lists in SharePoint:

- List01

  - Title (Text)
  - Status (Text)
- List02

  - Title (Text)
  - Status (Choice)

Then you can create a collection with the contents of both lists by using this expression:

```
ClearCollect(
    ItemsCollection,
    ShowColumns(
        AddColumns(List01, "StatusText", Status),
        "Title", "StatusText"));
Collect(
    ItemsCollection,
    ShowColumns(
        AddColumns(List02, "StatusText", Status.Value),
        "Title", "StatusText"));
```

The expression above creates a new column (*) called 'StatusText' on both lists, normalizing the type of the Status column to text, and then select the Title and StatusText columns from the two lists, thus ensuring that the schema (types of the fields) are the same.

(*) The AddColumns function doesn't create any additional columns in the SharePoint list; instead, it returns a new "virtual" table that can be used within expressions / controls in PowerApps.